# Add timestamp to apache error.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, timestamp, config, error-logging

how can I add a timestamp to apache error.log?
in the apache config-file I can change the path:

*ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error. log*

but what about adding timestamps?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us few lines from your current error_log?